# Get information from a parent controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to show a nav tab menu from "menupersonas" controller in a file called "top_layout.html.erb"

I'm trying to show that menu with a render but from "personas" and "personascorreos" views:

"/personas/4/edit" and "/personascorreos/index.html.erb"

this way:

```
<%= render file: "menupersonas/top_layout" %>
```

I clarify that "personas" has_many "personascorreos"

so the link in the menu(top_layout.html.erb) that I need to show is "link_to(persona_personastelefonos_path(persona))"

But I got this error: "undefined local variable or method `persona'"

I think know that the problem is that `@personascorreos = @persona.personascorreos.all` is not defined in `menupersonas` controller

But my question is: Is there a way to call that information from `personascorreos` without need to define it again in `menupersonas`?

Comment: I recommend that you always set up your data from your controllers. Is `@persona` set for each case where you need the `top_layout`?

Comment: No @persona is not set, but that's what I want to do, is there a way to do it withouth need to define persona in each controller or how should I define it ? I dont know how to do it because it should be like this "localhost:3000/personas/1/personascorreos" how do I get the id ?

Comment: You should set @persona from each controller. (You can even share the code which sets @persona by placing it in a module and mixing it into each controller).

For a request to "/personas/1/personascorreos" the Persona id should be accessible in the params Hash like `params[:persona_id]`. Take a look at your routes (`rake routes`) if something is unclear. Also the documentation here is very good http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you render a view from another (as any partial) the controller method isn't called.

I think you're missing the passing of locals when rendering the view. Try:

`<%= render file: "menupersonas/top_layout", persona: @persona %>`

or whatever defines the local that is missing from your rendered view.

GL & HF.

Comment: I dont know what happens but continue the same problem "undefined local variable or method `persona'"

Comment: @Andru1989 The persona missing is in your top_layout view, right? Where do you define it? Is it supposed to be the persona from which personascorreos? (since you're calling it from the index). Is it possible to define the local variable as I suggested? (maybe not `persona: @persona` but a different expression like `persona: @correospersonas.persona`. What is the intended behaviour? What are you using this menu for?